# How do I get the owner JAXBContext for an XmlAdapter?

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to install the `DefaultValidationEventHandler` for a particular `XmlAdapter`.
From what I've read you can only do this like:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyAdapter.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
um.setEventHandler(new DefaultValidationEventHandler());
```

However this is not possible because the `JAXBContext` is global and implicitly created (by Spring?) in our application.
Is there any way I can get the `JAXBContext` for my `session` ?

Comment: Well considering that the validation handler is actually configured on the Unmarshaller ... not the JAXBContext. So what exactly is the problem again?

Comment: You will notice the Unmarshaller is created from context, so you need the context first..

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1 of Your Question

> How do I get the owner JAXBContext for an XmlAdapter?

By default an implementation of `XmlAdapter` is only passed the object that it needs to convert.  If you want your `XmlAdapter` to maintain state you can set an instance of it on the `Marshaller`/`Unmarshaller`, then instead of a new instance being created this instance will be used.

```
XmlAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(jaxbContext);
unmarshaller.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

---

### Part 2 of Your Question

> I need to install the DefaultValidationEventHandler for a particular
>   XmlAdapter

This probably isn't what you want to do.  If you want special handling for certain objects I would create a class that extends `Unmarshaller.Listener` and implements `ValidationEventHander`.  And set this instance accordingly on your `Unmarshaller`.  Then you will be aware which object you are handling when doing your validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers above. Unfortunately I still don't know how to get hold of the jaxbContext in new MyAdapter(jaxbContext)